# What happened to Hierophant Green's painting power?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In episode two of Stardust Crusaders, Kakyoin paints red paint on a horribly drawn painting of Jotaro, specifically, on his leg. Jotaro gets a cut on his leg somehow. But Kakyoin never does it again. Why didn't he use it in more battles?

Comment: He could've used it when fighting High Priestess and won easily by erasing her teeth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure he never used it again because during the High Priestess arc, they were underwater and I'm sure Kakyoin would not have brought a canvas while they were on a submarine, but even if he did, they were underwater the whole time, making it pretty much impossible for him to paint under it.

And before you say "Oh, he could have injured Midler and make her revoke her stand", he didn't know what she looked like, and he needs to know what his victims look like before he paints them.

Comment: I like your answer. It takes common sense and actually uses it, instead of saying "Araki Forgot". Really creative.

Comment: @okaythatscool it was never stated that he had such ability in the first place. Never mentioned in stand stats description (in the manga), never to be seen again. It's common sense to think it was a prop to raise suspicion of this unknown character.

Answer (score 2):

Because he never had such an ability.

The painting was just a prop. As soon as Kakyoin stroke the canvas, he had Hierophant cut Jotaro. While this is not stated, it's heavily implied because as soon as he painted Jotaro, he threw the painting into a tree, signifying its unimportance, instead of using it again when he confronted Jotaro.

Comment: Wouldn't Jotaro just have seen Hierophant?

Comment: Kakyoin was camping in a tree. I don't think he would've seen Hierophant because, after the attack, Kakyoin de-summoned Heirophant.